# Where to define callback functions so that the calling object is still in scope?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

I want my ESP8266-based device to create an accesspoint that allows the user to input their home ssid and password. There is a device object that holds most of the data defined elsewhere.

I'm trying to use the ESP8266WebServer library. It requires me to define parameterless callback functions. Where should I declare and define these callback functions so that they can access the server object? In all the example code, the server object is global. I'd want to avoid that, and I'd also like to avoid having a server object as a permanent Device class member.

How should I go about this? It is not allowed to define the callback functions inside Device::getWifiCredentials, and if I declare them outside then server isn't in scope.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

// Function to create AccessPoint to get ssid and password
int Device::getWifiCredentials() {

    ESP8266WebServer server(80);
    server.begin();
    
    // define callbacks
    server.on("/", handleRoot); // initial page

    server.on("/ssid", handleCredentials); // catch response from initial page

    // wait for credentials to be delivered
    server.handleClient();

    while( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(500);
    }

    return ACTION_SUCCESSFUL;

}

// **Where can these functions be defined to allow them to access the server object?**

void handleRoot() {
};

void handleCredentials() {

    String ssid;
    String pw;

    if( server.hasArg() ){
        ssid = server.arg("ssid");
        pw = server.arg("pw");
    }
};
```

Comment: Your server need to be accessible.  At least through a global pointer.  A funcion without parameters cannot be a non-static member function, so all shared data must then be accessible globally.  A global pointer to a stack variable is not a very neat solution.  Why don't you want your server to be global?  It's not like you have multpile cores and threads running, or anything like that.  Global variables are somewhat of a necessity in embedded deviices.  Just like side effects are what embedded processors are made for.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Global variables really are not a necessity; they’re a lazy coding practice perpetuated by the way the Arduino Core is written. That said, a global is really necessary here due to the design of the web server library.

Comment: @romkey  I understand what you mean, I do program for servers and apps as well.  The concepts global variabes are indeed bad, because global state :is bad, and then there is a need for synchronizing threads, cores, and memory.  But the reality of microcontroller harware, and of microcontroller programming, is that the hardware is made to control gflobal state and EXPECTS the software running on it to produce side effects.  If you want to avoid state and side effects,  you may as well run your IoT straight on a server rack in an Amazon server farm.

Comment: @romkey  For example, when reading your code here.  I am kind of puzzled...  While waiting for connection,, your device cannot do anything else...  It cannot flash an LED, read a switch, check iits battery voltage...  Waiting  500ms for a switch to respoind would make for a terrible user experience.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy this is not my code.

Comment: @romkey  Well, the person who wrote it doesn't understand embedded device programming.  As a result,, the architecture doesn't fit with how 3rd party libraries are designed.  The OP has the choice: change the application so they can use the library, or write their own library just so that it fots the application.

Comment: @romkey  Sorry about mistaking you  for the OP.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy no harm done :)

Comment: @romkey I'm aware that the current code locks up the device. That's just a placeholder while I work on getting my code to compile. :-) Thanks for the help. I guess I just have to accept some global objects and move on.

Comment: @BjornEriksson I wasn't criticizing your code or you. Suggestion, though, check out [ESPAsyncWebServer](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer), it's a better designed, full featured web server.